# How to add an extra permission in sales module

Tags: security, user-permissions, odoo-12

i am using odoo version 12

currently the sales module has different permission like **Manager**, **User: Own Documents Only**, **User: All documents**

I need to add one more permission  to view all documents for the user like **User: View all Documents**. while selecting the permission of the sales module during the user creation  form

Please help me to fix this problem
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Prajith .P

You have to create the new `security` `group` and added on the `sales` `category`

```
<record id="group_sale_view_all_documents" model="res.groups">
    <field name="name">User: View all Documents</field>
    <field name="category_id" ref="base.module_category_sales_management"/>
    <field name="implied_ids" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
</record>
```

Comment: But it look like check box not in drop down how to fix this  help me please

Comment: did you try this and make the group and put on the existing sale category?